# Import Corine Land Cover in PostGis

Tags: postgis

I've imported a shapefile from the Corine Land Cover dataset in PostGis. I'm working on a software which will allow for diverse simulations on the territory.
This software integrates a function to connect in a database PostGis, my shapefile CLC when imported into PostGIS has no classification of the type of ground in the display.

However, when I import directly to the shapefile "raw" without passing through PostGis, the type of ground is shown well on the software.

This software already integrates the table with the codes CLC but it does not seem to work with tables of PostGis...

Thus it is a problem at the level of PostGis? Nevertheless in the table, I have well the column which defines the type(chap) of land use.

Comment: How did you do the import?  Postgres does not generally randomly exclude columns. shp2pgsql will always import everything, although column names will get truncated, but this is an issue with the shp file, not with Postgres.

Comment: I did the import with the plugin of postgres shapefile and dbf loader. But all my columns is fully import.